# why is Latex referencing differently to Endnote

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

Hello I am new to Latex so please go easy.
I have googled this very simple thing but found no conclusive answer:

I am trying to enter my references into my text the way that it is done in Endnote:

```
"Piece of text (Valouev et al., 2011)."

Valouev, A., Johnson, S. M., Boyd, S. D., Smith, C. L., Fire, A. Z. and Sidow, A. (2011) Determinants of nucleosome organization in primary human cells. Nature, 474, 516-20.
```

However no matter what referencing style I select in Latex, it gives me this format:

```
"Piece of text *Valouev et al. (2011)*"
Valouev, A., Johnson, S. M., Boyd, S. D., Smith, C. L., Fire, A. Z. and Sidow, A. (2011) Determinants of nucleosome organization in primary human cells. Nature, 474, 516-20.
```

Note that the author name is outside the brackets...

My Latex implementation is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apa}
......
\bibliography{reports}
\end{document}
```

Can anyone tell me how to have it in the way that Endnote does it so that the text looks cleaner?

Comment: The [TeX-UK FAQ](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-whatbst.html) links to a page by [Reed University](http://www.reed.edu/cis/help/LaTeX/bibtexstyles.html) which covers this rather nicely. Also if you're new to TeX and friends `texdoc --view PACKAGE`will show the help documentation for `PACKAGE`  (Took me ages before I stumbled upon this one) e.g. `texdoc --view visualFAQ` is quite useful. Happy TeXing !!!

Answer (score 9):

The `natbib` package defines the `\citet` command for in-text citations, and `\citep` for parenthetical citations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\citet{article-full} said so.

This is so \citep{article-full}


\bibliographystyle{apa}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```